# Алмаз, сапфир, рубин, аметист - конкретные или вещественные имена существительные?

Tags: морфология, существительные

Скажите, пожалуйста, **алмаз, рубин, сапфир, аметист**, то есть имена существительные, называющие драгоценные, полудрагоценные камни, относятся к конкретным или вещественным? Меня смущает их изменяемость по числам (рубин-рубины), сочетаемость с определенно-количественными числительными (два, три алмаза), но, с другой стороны, они обозначают какое-то вещество.

Comment: Аленушка, так собирательные (как в заголовке) или вещественные (как в вопросе)?

Comment: Спасибо, исправила.